# How write posix waitpid() analog for windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, posix

I want to port my linux code to windows. I don't want use cygwin or mingw. I would like to do this via WinApi. So who can help me to write waitpid() analog under windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateProcess` the way to create a new process. Its output is PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. `WaitForSingleObject` could wait for the end of the process.

Here is the example from [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) (`GetExitCodeProcess` was added.):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    DWORD exit_code = 0;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d)\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Get exit code
    GetExitCodeProcess( pi.hProcess, &exit_code );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Comment: This is not news for me @Naszta. I'm not asking about creating process. I'm asking about waiting untill process finishes and getting its exit status. The code you post here doesn't give me exit status of spawned process.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan: you should use: `GetExitCodeProcess` function. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use WaitForSingleObject if you have a process handle.  You should have obtained that when creating the child process.

Comment: how get status via WaitForSingleObject? The question not about wait(), its about waitpid().

Comment: You use WaitForSingleObject to wait it's termination, you use GetExitCodeProcess to get it's exit code - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Or specify a 0 timeout to get the state.  Or use OpenProcess() to get the process handle.