# C++ cmd displays the current dir before the output of my program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've made a program which attaches to a console if it's run from `cmd`, creates a child process, and redirects the output of the child process to the console.

The program is working pretty well, but there is one annoying issue: for some reason, when I run my program from the Windows Terminal, the line that shows the current directory is displayed before the output of the program:

[image: ISSUE]

The program itself is closed after its output (the executable not visible in Task Manager).

After I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (no other key works, and I can even input batch commands and they work, like `echo hello` and it will display `hello`):

[image: AFTER]

Here is the program:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

// help binding IOs to the attached console
void bindCrtHandleToStdHandle()
{
    FILE* dummyFile;
    freopen_s(&dummyFile, "nul", "w", stdout);

    // Redirect unbuffered stdout to the current standard output handle
    HANDLE stdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (stdHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int fileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)stdHandle, _O_TEXT);
        if (fileDescriptor != -1)
        {
            FILE* file = _fdopen(fileDescriptor, "w");
            if (file != NULL)
            {
                int dup2Result = _dup2(_fileno(file), _fileno(stdout));
                if (dup2Result == 0)
                {
                    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout.clear();
}

void readOutput(HANDLE hStdoutRead, std::atomic<bool>& exit) {
    const int bufferSize = 4096;
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    while (!exit) {
        // Check if there is data available to read from the pipe
        bool peekSuccess = PeekNamedPipe(hStdoutRead, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (!peekSuccess || bytesRead == 0) {
            // No data available, sleep for a short time before checking again
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            continue;
        }

        bool readSuccess = ReadFile(hStdoutRead, buffer, bufferSize, &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (readSuccess && bytesRead > 0) {
            std::cout.write(buffer, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    // Attach to the console is run from cmd to redirect stdout from the child process
    bool runFromConsole = AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    if (runFromConsole) {
        bindCrtHandleToStdHandle();
    }

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    HANDLE hStdoutRead, hStdoutWrite;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&hStdoutRead, &hStdoutWrite, &saAttr, 0)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Auto close the handles
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&CloseHandle)> stdoutReadHandle(hStdoutRead, &CloseHandle);
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&CloseHandle)> stdoutWriteHandle(hStdoutWrite, &CloseHandle);

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for stdout is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hStdoutRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    si.hStdOutput = hStdoutWrite;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    std::wstring commandLine = L"hello.exe";
    if (!CreateProcessW(
        NULL,
        &commandLine[0],
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi)
        )
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Launch the threads to read from the pipes
    std::atomic<bool> exit(false);
    std::thread outputThread(readOutput, hStdoutRead, std::ref(exit));

    // Wait for the process to finish
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    exit = true;

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    outputThread.join();

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `hello.exe` test program:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::cout << "HELLO WORLD!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I noticed if I call my program from a batch script with `program.exe > out.txt & pause`, the output does not get redirected to the file, but is visible in the console instead. But, if I do `program.exe > out.txt` in an existing terminal, there is no output in the file or the terminal.

For some context, my program's role will be to modify environment variables and pass them to another program, which can be either a console application or a GUI application. That's why I need `wWinMain()` and to attach to a console if there is one.

Any idea?

Comment: Your program exits and the command line appears.  Then the child outputs its data.  So, if you organize it so that the main program waits for the child's output before exiting that would fix the problem.    Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487249/how-write-posix-waitpid-analog-for-windows

Comment: Windows Terminal is different to Console to which the console APIs apply.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah My program already waits for the child with `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);`. Also, the child does not output anything directly to the console : it's the main program that captures the output of the child and write it to the console.